# Crystal Report get Percentage based on Group

Tags: asp.net, report, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-2010

### listed below multiple salesmen values comes in single report and Single Procedure

==========Salesman1====           Months         =====     Percentage

```
                  M1        25           25% 
                  M2        30           30%
                  M3        45           45%
                          ------- how to get the % value based on total of
                  Total    100
```

==========
Salesman2     ===         Months             ==== Percentage

```
                  M1        12.5           25%
                  M2        15             30%
                  M3        22.5           45%
                          -------       
                  Total      50
```

i Calling some Value based on the Procdeure and added on the crystal report based on Count . i need the percentage of the particular salesman on the on the percentage but my parameter value brings all the count of all the salesman i cannot take the percentage based on the parameter value . instead of changing my procedure is there anyway to get the percentage of the given group by value

MY store Procedure Parameter are Months and salesmen

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In crystal reports you can create a formula field. Once you open the Formula Editor there is an inbuilt function of "PercentageBySum" which you can use and then drop this field besides your month. It will give you percentage for all values based on group total